# ImportError: cannot import name 'render_to_response' from 'django.shortcuts'

Tags: python, django

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
ImportError: cannot import name 'render_to_response' from 'django.shortcuts' (C:\Users\gtdra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py)
```

I have this error when i migrate `django-chroniker` into my django project , i read that `render_to_response` have been remove since Django 2.0 , how can i fix this error ?? thanks you

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render

Comment: Have you tried searching the Django documentation?

Answer (score 3):

`render_to_response` is not available in `django.shortcuts` (The render_to_response shortcut was deprecated in Django 2.0, and is removed in Django 3.0.). You can make use of `render` like below

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def myview(request):
    return render(request, 'template.htmll', {'hi': 'hello'})
```

Comment: yes i use that , but when i migrate django-chroniker it has import error render_to_response , i think that django-chroniker use that render_to_response but i don't know how to fix it

Comment: @namphan then you have to update that repository my creating a PR :P